# Pass url parameter with ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was wondering if it is possible to pass an authToken parameter in the URL when executing a ajax post

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'myurl?token=' + authToken ,
  type: 'POST',
  data: jsonData,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
      // Get result from post
  },

});
```

If it is possible how would my web api capture the token along with the json data that is to be added to my db?

Comment: What is your server-side technology?

Comment: you can capture the token with $_GET['token'] if you are using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

```
$.ajax({
   url : myurl,
   headers: {
        'X-Auth-Token' : token
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and it is possible to pass the parameter in the url